# Is there a library what that implements pusher.com in node.js?

Tags: node.js, pusher

I use pusher.com and want to migrate to my own hosting. Is there a library that implements the Pusher.com protocol in Node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Slanger](https://github.com/stevegraham/slanger) is an open source implementation of the Pusher protocol written in Ruby; I'm not familiar with one written in Node. Note that the protocol [is fairly documented](http://pusher.com/docs/pusher_protocol), so if you really needed it for Node you could potentially write one.